# 【Django】Is writing all of the table definition in one model bad practice?

Tags: python, django

I'm confused at Where I have to write table definition .
Django have several apps and each app have models.
Table definition is written in the models.
However, table relationships is comprecated,so each app calls each other's model.It is comprecated and hard to find what app have a table.

So,I want to put all of the table definition into one app.

```
project
 myapp
  models.py(just have business logics)    
  views.py
 common
   models.py(just table definition)
  views.py
```

This is simple and easy to understand,I think.
Is this bad idea?

Comment: This is a common practice when integrating legacy (not Django managed) databases. If you have a Django managed database keep the models at the app they belong to.

Comment: Thanks for your replay.If one table is related to multiple functions(apps), How do i judge where to put the model?

Comment: If you can't figure that out then you might have spliti your apps too far.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I figure out that if I can properly split apps , i can tell where a model is .